# IIS 10 gives me an "ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME" when trying to connect with WS://

Tags: asp.net, websocket, iis-10

I have set up the WebSocket support on the server. 
I run windows 10 and IIS 10. 
I tried to add the ws as an allowed protocol in the site, but that did not help.

I'm running all on localhost.

Comment: And I am running in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I missunderstood something. I could not connect directly to the websocket handler. This had to be done in JS, through the WS object.

Comment: Please add some more specific information if you've already got the exact reason.