# WebSocket connection failed, error during WebSocket handshake

Tags: asp.net

I am calling an external API and displaying that page in an iframe in asp.net webforms, but I'm getting the error

```
VM1815:35 WebSocket connection to 'wss://service....com/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=k67e0dxBnudBQaxOAAAW' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

This is how I call the API

```
ClientsContent.InnerHtml = "<iframe src=\"" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SelfServiceURL"] + "/#/clients/list?auth=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthToken"].ToString()) + "&hideMenu=true\" style=\"border: 0; position:absolute; width:100%; height: 100%\" scrolling=\"yes\"></iframe>";
```

And when I try to access wss://selfservice.integration.livongo.com/browser-sync/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=VCEbf_z2jafcM1asAAAD, I receive ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME.

What could cause this? The page works fine, but the page displays this error in the Console. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried running the console as admin?

Comment: I mean -- the javascript Console

Comment: Is your external API using some kind of authentication?

Comment: Yes, this is how I call it  

    ClientsContent.InnerHtml = "<iframe src=\"" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SelfServiceURL"] + "/#/clients/list?auth=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpContext.Current.Session["AuthToken"].ToString()) + "&hideMenu=true\" style=\"border: 0; position:absolute; width:100%; height: 100%\" scrolling=\"yes\"></iframe>";

Answer (score 0):

Several other people have had ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME.  (do a S/O search on that err).  The usual cause is because you are using ws:// or wss://  with an IFrame instead of http://.

ws:// or wss:// are used with websocket calls.  IFrames need http or https addresses.

Ref: [IIS 10 gives me an "ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME" when trying to connect with WS://](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168633/iis-10-gives-me-an-err-disallowed-url-scheme-when-trying-to-connect-with-ws)